# Output from CSV import in PHP function

Tags: php, html, csv, import

I have a function in PHP, which create a HTML table with data in CSV files.

The problem is the title of each table is twice printed. First in `<th>` and then in the first `<tr>`. I want the title only printed in the `<th>` and not in the following `<tr>`.
What is the mistake and do you have other recommendation for the PHP function.

**csv example**

```
title a, Titel A 
example1, Beispiel1
example2, Beispiel2

title b, Titel B
example1, Beispiel1
example2, Beispiel2
```

**php function**

```
function CreateLangTable($csvFile, $startRow, $endRow, $number) {
    global $lang_code1, $lang_code2, $vocabulary_group, $urlArray;

    if ($endRow < $startRow) {
        return;
    }
    echo ' 
  <a id="' . $vocabulary_group[$urlArray[4]][$number] . '"></a>  
 <div class="table-responsive">  
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-fixed">                           
    <thead class="blue-grey lighten-4">';
    $csvFile->seek($startRow);
    vprintf('
        <tr>  
          <th><div data-text="%1$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code1 . '" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</div></th> 
          <th><div data-text="%2$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code2 . '" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>', $csvFile->current());
    while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow) {
    vprintf('   
        <tr>
          <td><div data-text="%1$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code1 . '" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</div></td> 
          <td><div data-text="%2$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code2 . '" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</div></td>
        </tr>', $csvFile->current());
 $csvFile->next();              
    }

    echo '
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>' . "\n";
}
if ($urlArray[3] == "vokabeln" &&  isset($urlArray[4])) { // Undefined offset: 3 [only until /url1/url2/]
    $file = new SplFileObject($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$urlArray[1]/csv/$urlArray[4].csv");
    $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
}
```

**php code for generation the HTML tables for this CSV example:**

```
CreateLangTable($file, 0, 2, 0);
CreateLangTable($file, 4, 6, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$csvFile->seek($startRow);` line gets the pointer to the header.
Then the `while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow)` starts looping from the same point.
There should be a `$csvFile->next();` before 'while()'
That's
`$csvFile->next();`
`while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow) {...}`